# GeoServer: Can't open Layer Preview for single layer

Tags: geoserver, wms

In Geoserver Layer Preview I can't open preview for single layers, in case of Layer Groups it works fine, but when I click single layer preview, pop-ups download window with a "wms" named file which includes the text below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://dev.ozorix.com/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> 
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   
<ServiceException code="LayerNotDefined" locator="layers">
Could not find layer mygeorgia:mg_5_roads
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I searched the issue in Google for hours but didn't succeed, tried to change styles, projection, edit wms links - no improvement.

Does anyone know how to solve the issue?

[image]

Comment: Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: are you using GeoFence?

Comment: GeoServer Logs are empty, I am working for a company and this GeoServer is installed on remote server. I don't know what they use or installed.

Comment: you may need to turn logging on or up to see something then. You tagged the question with geofence - if it isn't involved then you should remove the tag, if it is then you need to add details of the settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally I've found out the reason myself.

"**OpenLayers**" works fine with **Single Layers** until they are not grouped twice (Child > Parent Groups).

The layers which are in "**Landcover_Group**", and then being "within Landcover_Group" are placed in "Road_Land" group, cannot be open with "**OpenLayers**".

The ones which are placed only in one group have no issues.